# how to link multiple lex generated c file?

Tags: lex

I write 3 .lex files for 3 different format file parsing, after generating scanner c code, I need to build these 3  file into a single executable but it failed for reason like “multiple definition of ＇yy_switch_to_buffer（...）＇”, “multiple definition of ＇yytext＇”, ...

How to solve this？

Comment: One of the most obvious ways would be to replace the `yy` that is part of every generated name with something else on a per-file basis. For example, you could replace it with `xx` in one file, `zz` in the second and leave it unchanged in the third.

Comment: Yes! use *%option prefix=“zz”* will replace the default functions with *zz*-prefixed macros. Also ylwrap in autotools seems only handle scanner c file named *lex.yy.c*, so *%option outfile=“lex.yy.c”* is needed too

Answer (score 0):

([Answered by the OP in a comment. Converted to a community wiki answer to suit the Q&A style of Stackoverflow.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))

The OP wrote:

> Use the `%option prefix=“zz”` to replace the default functions with zz-prefixed macros. Also `ylwrap` in autotools seems only handle scanner **C** file named `lex.yy.c`, so `%option outfile=“lex.yy.c”` is needed too.